# How to increase width for labels in formsFX?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: screenshot of my problem]

How to increase the number of labels letters shown by sacrificing the width of the text field in library formsFX? In my case, a maximum of 7 letters are shown.

Comment: Dmitry, I would gladly advise you to embed the image inside the post. It's not a good practice to link it from outer space.

Comment: [mcve] please .. something wrong with your layout constraints